# Calling angularjs function on text input based on length

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I have a text box. I would like to call a method inside controller only when user has filled in 'n' or more number of characters in the textbox.

Can someone please give me pointers on how to approach this?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Id recommend just using [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) and binding to an evaluation function. Below is a sample

```js
angular.module('inputChange', [])
    .controller('TextInputController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var inputMin = 3;
    $scope.someVal = '';
    $scope.result = '';
    $scope.textChanged = function() {
        if ($scope.someVal.length >= inputMin) executeSomething()
        else $scope.result = '';
    };

    function executeSomething() {
        $scope.result = $scope.someVal;
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="inputChange" ng-controller="TextInputController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="someVal" ng-change="textChanged()" ng-Trim="false" /> 
    <br />

    someVal: <span ng-bind="someVal"></span>
    <br />
    Result: <span ng-bind="result"></span>
    <br />
    someVal Length: <span ng-bind="someVal.length"></span>
    <br />
    Result Length: <span ng-bind="result.length"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: That would be an easy fix, just remove all spaces from within the `$scope.textChanged` function.

Comment: You can also add `ng-trim="false"` to the input tag to prevent the white space being automatically trimmed for the spacebar.

Answer (score 6):

You could simply achieve this by using `ng-keyup` directive

```
ng-keyup="(1myNgModel.length >= n) && myFunction()"
```

Desired function will only gets called only if length of model is greater than equal to `n` length

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/QZKnw2BdJh490J6P096R?p=preview)

---

Though the better version would be having `ng-model-options` with `debounce` time, so that it will reduce number of value change. After that we can easily use `ng-change` directive to fire function.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myNgModel" 
  ng-change="(myNgModel.length >= 3) && myFunction()" 
  ng-model-options="{ debounce: 200 }" />
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/HfPDC4veoW9KlVrC7Tly?p=preview)

Comment: This won't work--click events don't get fired on keypress events

Comment: This doesnt work. Here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/yVblywwJvhFh24bOtfwA?p=preview

Comment: wrap expression inside bracket and do replace n with some number

Comment: Wrapped. Please check the plunker

Comment: see working plunkr here, I only changed controller name..rest was working correctly

Comment: i think `ng-keypress` is better option than `ng-keyup`

Comment: @PardeepJain why? I would say its better fits would be using with ngModelOptions with debounce..

Comment: @PardeepJain check updated answer... it is much better than what I have added before, Thanks for heads up so that I improved answered quality :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a directive to your element and `$watch` for model changes. Then you can fire any logic you wish when your model has changed and has a value. In this case, lets call our model `expression`. Here is an example for a `<textarea>` element. This approach can just as well be used for an `<input />` element as well.

```
<textarea watcher ng-model="expression"></textarea>
```

---

```
app.directive('watcher', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (v) {
                if(v) {
                    // you have a value
                } else {
                    // no value
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/71yx0nw5/)

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do this is to use a directive. Here's how it might be done:

view:

```
<div ng-app="foo" ng-controller="fooController">
    <textarea text-length-handler="doThing()" text-length="6" ng-model="text">
    </textarea>
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('foo', [])
.directive('textLength', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            textLengthHandler: '&'
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrl) {
            var limit = parseInt($attrs.textLength);
            var handler = function(){
                if (ctrl.$modelValue.length >= limit) {
                    $scope.textLengthHandler()
                }
            };
            $element.on('keypress', handler);
            // remove the handler when the directive disappears
            $scope.$on('destroy', function(){
                $element.off('keypress', handler)
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dtq0mz8m/

Answer (score 0):

If you tie the input field to a variable using ngModel, you can watch it from the controller (is not very elegant, though) using $watch or $observe whenever it changes, and check the length.